# stdout from putty in text widget

Tags: tcl, putty

I'm using putty to connect with server and execute a command, but I have no idea how to redirect the command output to text widget.

```
exec patchtoputty/putty.exe -ssh myserver -pw mypass -m mycommand
```

Normally this should (?) works:

```
catch {exec patchtoputty/putty.exe -ssh myserver -pw mypass -m mycommand} results
.text insert 1.0 $results
```

but not in this case where I'm executing putty (or for example cygwin) command which has his own terminal window.

Regards,
lucas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very tricky to grab the output of a window and insert it into a text widget; you'd have to regularly grab the screen and OCR the results or something. Ridiculous.

But with putty, your best bet is to instead switch to plink.exe (= “Putty LINK” I think) from the same family. It's basically putty but without the windowing stuff and with the ability to run nicely in a pipeline. It takes the same options as putty, so modifying your code should be really easy.

```
catch {exec wherever/plink.exe -ssh myserver -pw mypass -m mycommand} results
.text insert 1.0 $results
```

(Building your own putty? Just make sure you build plink at the same time.)

Comment: plink is working nice but in my case when I want to execute a command using remote command "-m mycommand" I have an answear "bash: command not found". when I'm executing the same command after logging on server (not throught remote command) it's working well. I think plink has a problem to change an enviromnent when using remote command?

Comment: @lucas The running of remote commands is a complex topic (tl;dr: there's a _lot_ of things that can go wrong, and a lot of things you can tweak) and it's a while since I looked at the details of plink, but when going to any POSIX-ish system you can use `/usr/bin/env FOO=BAR mycommand` to set up a variable before running the command. That might help. (Or maybe not; I've not used plink manually for quite a while after all.)

Comment: I think the problem is that the command which I'm trying to execute is specific for the software which is installed on server. Plink is connecting with server and execute a command before he has response from the software, that's why he don't recognize a command. Maybe there is a way to connect through plink and execute a command in second step (not in one line)? Maybe Expect could be helpfull? But even that, I have problem to wrap it to .exe file (package not found message), or there are other easier way?

Comment: @lucas To me it sounds more like you're missing some kind of environment setting (special `PATH`?) that is set when you log in interactively but which isn't done when you use the “run a command remotely” mode. Which brings us back to “there's a _lot_ of things that can go wrong” unfortunately.